# How to use htmlspecialchars_decode in PHP

Tags: php

I am a inserting a content in FCKEDITOR.

**EXAMPLE Content** : TEST ~!@#$%^&*()_+| TEST

**But i get the output like this**: TEST ~!@')

What should i do to get the exact output?

I am using ajax to do this.

Thanks.

Fero

Comment: What should the end result look like?

Comment: I am inserting it in my DB. But the content not inserting 'Our 5 oz regular neck baby
> bottles are made from PES plastic,
> which gives them a natural golden
> color. They are free of phthalates and
> free of bisphenol A –' after this. I need to insert all the content.

Comment: Where does PHP come into this? FckEditor is JavaScript.

Comment: I too know that. I used javascript just to pass the value from  HTML to PHP. And i hope we can insert the value using FCKEDITOR and PHP. Sorry if am wrong – Fero 0 secs ago edit

Comment: If the string isn't complete in $_REQUEST, then the error is in the code passing it to PHP. Is each string you try to pass capped at the same number of characters?

Comment: yes. I get all the values when i alert the URL in java script.

Answer (score 0):

htmlspecialchars_decode is used to convert html encoded characters back to regular characters:

```
&amp; -> &
&nbsp; -> 'space'
&quot; -> "
```

You have no html encoded characters in the string you posted.

If you print the exact SQL statement you send to the DB, what do you see?

Is the field in the database long enough? Do strings always get cut of at the same length?

Comment: I didn't even get the full paragraph in my $_REQUEST itself.

Comment: I get only these contents instead of full content. 'Our 5 oz regular neck baby > bottles are made from PES plastic, > which gives them a natural golden > color. They are free of phthalates and > free of bisphenol A –'.

Comment: Are these fields posted or passed in the query string? (To check, see the $_POST en $_GET variables).